# Creating Chart with VBA, can't format X-Axis as Text

Tags: vba, excel, excel-charts

I am working on creating a macro that generates a chart.

The chart creation works as I expected, no issues there.  The only problem I have is that the dates being shown in the X-Axis are incorrect.

```
Sub generateChart()
' Select a range starting in row 2.
' This macro will use that range, and create a chart just for them.
Dim rng As Range
Dim randR As Long, randG As Long, randB As Long

Set rng = Selection

Dim numCharts As Long
numCharts = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count

Dim newChart As ChartObject

Dim num As Long
num = rng.Columns.Count

Dim i       As Long

For i = 1 To num
    randR = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 200)
    randG = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
    randB = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)

    With ActiveSheet
        Set newChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Width:=400, Top:=75, Height:=225)
        With newChart.Chart
            .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
            Debug.Print rng.Address

            .SetSourceData Source:=rng

            With .FullSeriesCollection(1)
                .Name = Cells(1, rng.Columns(i).Column).Value
                .Values = Range(Cells(2, rng.Columns(i).Column), _
                                Cells(rng.Rows.Count + 1, rng.Columns(i).Column))
                .XValues = "=Sheet2!$J$2:$J$10"
                .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(randR, randG, randB)
                .Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
                .MarkerStyle = 1
                .MarkerSize = 8
            End With

            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            With .FullSeriesCollection(2)
                .Name = "=Sheet2!$Q$1"
                .Values = "=Sheet2!$Q$2:$Q$10"
                .XValues = "=Sheet2!$J$2:$J$10"
                .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
                .MarkerStyle = 0
            End With

            .SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)

            ' Add titles
            Dim titleStr As String
            .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
            titleStr = Cells(1, rng.Columns(i).Column).Value & " Time Delay"

            With .ChartTitle
                .Text = titleStr
                .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Cells(1, rng.Columns(i).Column).Value & " Time Delay"
                .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
                .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
            End With

            ' Now, hide the points that are 0 value
            hideZeroValues newChart

            ' I thought this would work, but it doesn't seem to do anything
            .Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale

        End With 'newchart.chart

    End With                 ' ActiveSheet
Next i

End Sub
```

And a screenshot:
[image]
Note that I don't even have the option to format as text.

(Note the averages are correct, there's hidden columns)

However! If I create a chart with the "built-in" chart, just by selecting the data, I *can* choose to format as text.

What am I overlooking in my Macro?  Why can't I seem to set the X-Values correctly?  Choosing "Number", then formatting as Date category keeps the incorrect dates.  Finally, and perhaps it's a hint at what's going wrong, if I right click the chart, and try to Select Date, the "Horizontal Axis" is greyed out.

Thanks for any thoughts/ideas!

Edit: Here's a [link to a .gif, showing the formatting working correctly, if I insert the chart via Excel's chart menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnPIL.gif)

Comment: you need to select the axis to format it. The screenshot shows the chart area formatting dialog, not the x axis formatting dialog.

Comment: @teylyn - Ah, yeah sorry. That screenshot I forgot to select it, but when when I *do* select the X-Axis, it shows the same options. Nothing to show as Text.

Comment: @BruceWayne Not sure I understand, do you mean to format the `X-Values` as `Text` ? Do you mean `.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "@"` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado - Kind of. I'll update with a .gif of when it *does* work. Note that if I choose as `Text`, with `@`, I get the "Excel" version of the dates, i.e. `42450`, not `4/30/2016`.

Comment: @BruceWayne and `.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"` ? It's working for me when testing with the data you have in your post

Comment: @ShaiRado - No :( ...it correctly *formats* to that, but for some reason is still changing the date itself. What I expect to see as `30/04/2016` is showing as `03/21/2016`...And the dates are entered straight up as `4/30/2016` and the format is `Date`.  See my edit to OP, I included a link to a .gif showing how it *does work* via Insert --> Chart.  I've even thought it was because I was including that extra cell, `J1`, but when adjusting the ranges in the macro, I still get the wrong dates.

Comment: I think what you're seeing is the difference between a Categorical x-axis and a Continuous one.  "Scatter"-type plots use Continuous axes (ie. they plot the "range" of data, not just the individual points, and the displayed dates are determined by the major/minor tick intervals).

Comment: What if instead of setting `.XValues = "=Sheet2!$J$2:$J$10"` we drop this and use `chart.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryNames = Range("Sheet2!$J$2:$J$10")`? Maybe forcing the `names` obliges to take the data as strings?

Comment: @A.S.H - I commented out the `.XValues` part, and after that `With` statement added your suggestion. It creates a crazy and really condensed X-Axis, pushing the data apart.  ...and still, won't let me format as Text. :/ - should I have put that somewhere else?

Comment: @TimWilliams - Aha!!! Yes, you're on to something!  If I change the Axis Units to say `80` for Major, then the first date is `01/31/2016`. Therefore, I think my VBA is working correctly, meaning it's not that the X-Axis is being set incorrectly ...I just have to figure out what my `Major` units need to be, to get just the dates I want to show?  ...how come though, using the *same* chart type via Insert--> Chart, the dates I want already show up, and I *can* Format as Text? What's my VBA doing that the Insert Chart isn't?

Comment: Well with the `CategoryNames` method (that I set just at the end when all of the chart is made), I dont see the pattern you mentioned. Notice we can control the density of the lables using `Axis.TickLabelSpacing`... (or something else idk)

Comment: @BruceWayne maybe that option you're mentioning is available through         x.TickLabels.NumberFormat = xlText (as ShaiRado had mentioned already but with a date format).

Comment: @A.S.H - It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LOmX.jpg) when adding that to the very end.  Doing `.TickLabels.Numberformat = xlText` also formats it funky. The dates become just `-4158`.  I'm worried that I can't get what I want, via the `Chart` method.  When recording the Insert-Chart, it uses a `Shape` to create the chart. So far, tweaking that seems to keep the X-Axis as text.  Perhaps it's an issue with the `ChartObjects` generally?? (doing `ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine)` is what I'm trying now.

Comment: Don't use a scatter plot, just use the "regular" line plot

Comment: On a side notice you can control the orientation of the labels, i.e. making them 45 degrees will look better IMO. i.e. consider x.TickLabels.Orientation = 45 (and you're right setting to xlText doesn't seem to work)

Comment: Use this: `newChart.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale` if your line chart still defaults to "continuous" x-axis.

Comment: @TimWilliams - ...Wow, that did it! I used just `xlLine` as the chart type, and then added the ` ...CategoryType = xlCategoryScale` to the end, and it's working! ...I was looking at this way too long, and didn't even consider it would be the chart type.  Thanks a zillion everyone for your help! (Perhaps you can make it an answer, because I've run into this before without realizing it)?  But sincere thanks to all :D :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're seeing is the difference between a Categorical x-axis and a Continuous one. "Scatter"-type plots use Continuous axes (ie. they plot the "range" of data, not just the individual points, and the displayed dates are determined by the major/minor tick intervals).

You should use a "regular" line chart (not the "scatter" version) and if it still doesn't behave then:

```
newChart.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale
```

should force the x-axis to Categorical mode

Comment: That line, combined with using `.ChartType = xlLine` did the trick. Thanks a lot!